# Validator, and input-validation-error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation

I do have a View bound to a model,

When I am using a built-in Validator on a property in the model, [EmailAddress] for instance, if I write something invalid, the html tag gets the class input-validation-error. Which allows me to display it in red via css. That's works perfectly.

But when I am using my custom validators, like :

```
public class CONT_RU06Attribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            int value = int.Parse(value.ToString());

            if (value < 2 || value > 6)                
                return new ValidationResult("Value must be between 2 and 6");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

The bound html tag does not get the input-validation-error class...
What can I do ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement <kbd>[IClientValidatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)</kbd> also

```
public class CONT_RU06Attribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            int value = int.Parse(value.ToString());

            if (value < 2 || value > 6)                
                return new ValidationResult("Value must be between 2 and 6");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule();
        rule.ErrorMessage = FormatErrorMessage(metadata.GetDisplayName());           
        rule.ValidationType = "range";
        yield return rule;
    }

}
```

[Check this article](http://www.itorian.com/2013/08/enabling-client-side-validation-on.html)